# Открытие файла в стороннем приложении

Tags: java, android, android-intent

```
 private void openInOtherApp(String filePath) {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    if (file.exists() && file.isFile()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("file:///" + file.toString()));
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(LibraryActivity.this, file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

При попытке открыть файл сторонним приложением вылетает ошибка

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent

Возникает это либо при отсутствии приложения, которое может открыть данный формат, либо оно не задано по умолчанию. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то типа такого. Не могу проверить, студии нет под рукой.

```
private void openInOtherApp(String filePath) {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    if (file.exists() && file.isFile()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String type = getMIMEType(filePath);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) { 
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(LibraryActivity.this, file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public static String getMimeType(String url) {
    String type = null;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
    if (extension != null) {
        type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
    return type;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь и диалог показывает для открытия